# Creating thumbnails of uploaded images

Tags: php, jquery, thumbnails

I have a system for uploading user's images to a server and database. I'm having trouble figuring out a way to create thumbnail copies of these images (for example, 100 pixels in height, hopefully at a smaller file size) to be saved into the same directory as the original, using the current setup. A user may at any time be uploading more than one image simultaneously.

I'm using an upload method derived from blueimp jQuery-file-upload, found here:
http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
// A list of permitted file extensions

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){
$image = $_FILES['upl'];
$image_name = $image['name'];
$setComic = $_POST['uplComID'];
$id = base_convert(microtime(false), 10, 36).end($image_name);
$upload_path = 'comics/'.$setComic.'/';
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');
$extension = strtolower(pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if (!file_exists($upload_path)) 
{
    mkdir($upload_path, 0777, true);
}

if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed))
{
    echo '{"status":"error"}';
    exit;
}

if(move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $upload_path.$id))
{

    include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');
    $pageNum = 1;
    $pageCheck = 0;

    while($pageCheck == 0) 
    {
        $query = ("SELECT pageNum FROM page WHERE comicID = '".$setComic."' AND pageNum = '".$pageNum."'");
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
        {
            mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO page(pageNum, pageLocation, comicID) VALUES('".$pageNum."', '".$upload_path.$id."', '".$setComic."')");     
            $pageCheck++;
        }
        else
        {
            $pageNum++;
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

}

}


?>
```

Thanks in advance. If any further code is required please just ask. If what I'm asking is too much to answer in one question I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction regarding tutorials, as I have little experience in thumbnail creation.

Comment: Look at: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php Imagick is very helpful for modifying images, you'll need to install the php5 imagick module as well though